# How Firefox creates the website tiles in New Tab?

Tags: firefox

The tiles in the "new Tab" window of the recently used websites consist sometimes of a small logo and a website screenshot and sometimes of just one big logo? 
What is the algorithm for the creation of the tiles?
My own website is displayed as small logo (favicon) in bottom right corner and a totally blank screenshot. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component responsible for doing that is called `activity-stream` and is developed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mozilla/activity-stream). The code is then mirrored into the Firefox codebase when a new release is created.

As far as I can tell, the code responsible for fetching a website's icon for the tiles is [this](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/137f1b2f434346a0c3756ebfcbdbee4069e15dc8/browser/extensions/activity-stream/lib/TopSitesFeed.jsm#168-192) which, in order, tries:

- checks if the website provided a *favicon* which has an [high enough](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/137f1b2f434346a0c3756ebfcbdbee4069e15dc8/browser/extensions/activity-stream/lib/TopSitesFeed.jsm#29) resolution (currently it's 96x96);
- verifies that there's a *tippy-top* fallback icon (probably from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/tippy-top-sites));
- tries to request a rich-icon from [here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/137f1b2f434346a0c3756ebfcbdbee4069e15dc8/browser/extensions/activity-stream/lib/FaviconFeed.jsm#117);
- if all the above fails, it tries to get a screenshot of the page and pin it in the tile.

As far as I can tell the easiest fix is to provide a good enough favicon from your website.

Comment: Thanks very much, perfect answer!